# jquery plugin to upload multiple files through IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload

I'm looking for multiple file uploader plugin using jquery and Ajax. I searched for such a plugin and found couple of jquery plugins that are supposed to work fine.

But, no plugin was able to select multiple files to upload in selection window except in Mozilla Firefox.

Even setting multiple in input type="file" didn't work in internet explorer.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

please suggest me a tool plugin which will offer selecting multiple files in internet explorer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com). It works fine in all the browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some good plugin lis.
First and last of them r my favorite  u can select what u prefer most.

[jQuery File Upload Plugin](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/08/5-best-jquery-file-upload-plugin.html)

Comment: HeyCRDave, Thanx for the anser i will try for Plupload.